# Haskell IO: convert IO String to "Other type"

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

I have a Haskell program which takes a file as an input and convert it into a binary search tree.

```
import System.IO    

data Tree a = EmptyBST | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

ins :: Ord a => a -> (Tree a) -> (Tree a)
ins a EmptyBST                  = Node a EmptyBST EmptyBST
ins a (Node p left right)
    | a < p                             = Node p (ins a left) right
    | a > p                             = Node p left (ins a right)
    | otherwise                             = Node p left right



lstToTree :: Ord a => [a] -> (Tree a)
lstToTree                   = foldr ins EmptyBST

fileRead                    = do    file    <- readFile "tree.txt"
                            let a = lstToTree (conv (words file))
                            return a

conv :: [String] -> [Int]
conv                        = map read
```

However, when I run the following command:

```
ins 5 fileRead
```

I got the following error:

```
<interactive>:2:7:
    Couldn't match expected type `Tree a0'
                with actual type `IO (Tree Int)'
    In the second argument of `ins', namely `fileRead'
    In the expression: ins 5 fileRead
    In an equation for `it': it = ins 5 fileRead
```

Please does anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You'd be able to see the problem right away if you supplied `fileRead` with a type signature. Let's figure out the type annotation that GHC will internally assign to `fileRead`:

```
fileRead = do file <- readFile "tree.txt"
              let t = lstToTree $ map read $ words file
              return t
```

`lstToTree :: Ord a => [a] -> Tree a`, and `read` always returns a member of the `Read` typeclass. So `t :: (Read a, Ord a) => Tree a`. The concrete type depends on the contents of the file.

`return` wraps its argument in a monad, so `return t` has the type `Ord a, Read a => IO (Tree a)`. Since `return t` is the final statement in the `do` block, it becomes the return type of `fileRead`, so

```
fileRead :: (Read a, Ord a) => IO (Tree a)
```

So `fileRead` is a `Tree` wrapped in an `IO`, and you can't pass it directly into `ins` because it expects a `Tree` on its own. You can't take the `Tree` out of the `IO`, but you *can* 'lift' the function `ins` into the `IO` monad.

Control.Monad exports [`liftM :: Monad m => (a -> r) -> (m a -> m r)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aliftM). It accepts a regular function, and turns it into one that acts on monads like `IO`. It's actually a synonym for [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afmap) (in the standard Prelude), since all monads are functors. So this code, roughly equivalent to @us202's, takes the result of `fileRead`, inserts `5`, and gives you back the result wrapped in an `IO`.

```
liftM (ins 5) fileRead
-- or --
fmap (ins 5) fileRead
```

I'd recommend the `fmap` version. This code only makes use of the fact that `IO` is a functor, so using `liftM` implies to the reader that you might need it to be a monad too.

'Lifting' is the general technique for using pure functions on values wrapped in monads or functors. If you're unfamiliar with lifting (or if you're confused by monads and functors in general), I heartily recommend chapters 11-13 of [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

---

PS. Note that the last two lines of `fileRead` should probably be combined, since `return` doesn't really do anything:

```
fileRead :: (Read a, Ord a) => IO (Tree a)
fileRead = do file <- readFile "tree.txt"
           return $ lstToTree $ map read $ words file
```

Or, since it's a short enough function, you could do away with `do` notation altogether and use `fmap` again:

```
fileRead :: (Read a, Ord a) => IO (Tree a)
fileRead = fmap (lstToTree . map read . words) (readFile "tree.txt")
```

---

**Edit in response to your comment:**

Haskell is *deliberately* designed to keep code that performs IO separate from regular code. There's a very good philosophical reason for this: most Haskell functions are "pure" - that is, their output depends only on the input, just like functions in maths. You can run a pure function a million times and you'll always get the same result. We like pure functions because they can't accidentally break other parts of your program, they permit laziness, and they allow the compiler to aggressively optimise your code for you.

Of course, in the real world we need a little bit of impurity. IO code like `getLine` can't possibly be pure (and a program that doesn't do IO is useless!). The result of `getLine` depends on what the user typed: you could run `getLine` a million times and get a different string every time. Haskell leverages the type system to label impure code with the type `IO`.

Here's the crux of the matter: if you use a pure function on data obtained impurely then the result is still impure, because *the outcome depends on what the user did*. So the whole calculation belongs in the `IO` monad. When you want to bring a pure function into `IO` you have to lift it, either explicitly (using `fmap`) or implicitly (with `do` notation).

This is a really common pattern in Haskell - look at my version of `fileRead` above. I've used `fmap` to operate on impure `IO` data with a pure function.

Comment: Hmm. The thing is, what I really want to be able to do is produce a function which can be called and returns an element of type Tree a. I.e. it reads the list in the text file, produces a tree via lstToTree or similar, and then returns that tree so that the user can run other functions similar to ins on it. Can this be done straightforwardly?

Comment: @MohammedAl-Farhan - That's a very good question, and to do it justice would take more than 600 characters. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really escape the IO monad (except through unsafe functions) but there's no actual need to do that in your case:

```
main = do f <- fileRead
          let newtree = ins 5 f
          putStr $ show newtree
```

(live demo: [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3JAOe5%2412))

Comment: Thanks, but I want the user enter any element that he wants to add to the list. I do not want the element be fixed

Comment: Then modify the above: Read the element via `getLine` and use that, add some kind of a loop to add many elements read from stdin, whatever you like.