# Can I create a function in Haskell that will encapsulate reading data from file and returning me a simple list of data?

Tags: haskell

Consider the code below taken from a working example I've built to help me learn Haskell. This code parses a CSV file containing stock quotes downloaded from Yahoo into a nice simple list of bars with which I can then work.

My question: how can I write a function that will take a file name as its parameter and return an OHLCBarList so that the first four lines inside main can be properly encapsulated?

In other words, how can I implement (without getting all sorts of errors about IO stuff) the function whose type would be

```
getBarsFromFile :: Filename -> OHLCBarList
```

so that the grunt work that was being done in the first four lines of main can be properly encapsulated?

I've tried to do this myself but with my limited Haskell knowledge, I'm failing miserably.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

type Filename = String
getContentsOfFile :: Filename -> IO BS.ByteString




barParser :: Parser Bar
barParser = do
   time <- timeParser
   char ','
   open  <-  double
   char ','
   high <- double
   char ','
   low <- double
   char ','
   close <- double
   char ','
   volume <- decimal
   char ','

   return $ Bar Bar1Day time open high low close volume



type OHLCBar = (UTCTime, Double, Double, Double, Double)

type OHLCBarList = [OHLCBar]

barsToBarList :: [Either String Bar] -> OHLCBarList



main :: IO ()
main = do


   contents :: C.ByteString <-  getContentsOfFile "PriceData/Daily/yhoo1.csv" --PriceData/Daily/Yhoo.csv"

   let lineList :: [C.ByteString] = C.lines contents -- Break the contents into a list of lines

   let bars :: [Either String Bar] =  map (parseOnly barParser) lineList  -- Using the attoparsec

   let ohlcBarList :: OHLCBarList = barsToBarList bars -- Now I have a nice simple list of tuples with which to work


   --- Now I can do simple operations like
  print $ ohlcBarList !! 0
```

Comment: The type has to be `Filename -> IO OHLCBarList`. Can you please format the code properly and remove the redundant screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want your function to have type `Filename -> OHLCBarList`, it can't be done.*  Reading the contents of a file is an IO operation, and Haskell's IO monad is specifically designed so that values in the IO monad can never leave.  If this restriction were broken, it would (in general) mess with a lot of things.  Instead of doing this, you have two options: make the type of `getBarsFromFile` be `Filename -> IO OHLCBarList` — thus essentially copying the first four lines of `main` — or write a function with type `C.ByteString -> OHLCBarList` that the output of `getContentsOfFile` can be piped through to encapsulate lines 2 through 4 of `main`.

* Technically, it *can* be done, but you *really, really, really* shouldn't even try, **especially** if you're new to Haskell.

Comment: Thank you --- (and to all the others who responded). I figured it couldn't be done, as I did understand (albeit not perfectly as I'm still a beginner) the type error messages but I had wondered whether there was something I was missing. At this point, I guess my struggle is more philosophical. I understand the reasons for separation of pure and impure functionality and I get (and love) the benefits of the strong type system. Yet the restriction prevents what would seem to be a very reasonable structural abstraction, that is, convert X to Y for any X & Y.

Comment: *"Yet the restriction prevents what would seem to be a very reasonable structural abstraction, that is, convert X to Y for any X & Y."*. Hmm, to me this seems as far from a reasonable abstraction as possible. Not all things should be seen as "convertible to any other thing"…

Comment: @David: I don't understand what abstraction is prevented. You can write the functions you want to write, you just have to throw in some `IO`s in their type. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem (at least from my limited understanding) is that one would have to propagate that IO throughout all functions. Every other language with which I've worked allows me to extract a block of code out of a method or procedure and make it standalone, with consequential improvements in readability, modularity and so forth but without any change in semantic behavior (at least if you do it right!) I'm thinking of Martin Fowler's refactoring work, for example. However, I'm still trying to learn the "best practices" around Haskell and perhaps one day this won't bother me.

Comment: @David see my amended answer for a more detailed explanation on how to extract code into pure functions. Also, your proposed function `cast :: a -> b` which converts X to Y for any X & Y is **unsafe**, and is strictly forbidden: How can a function convert between any two types while knowing nothing about their structure?

Comment: @David The sort of refactoring you're talking about is good and strongly encouraged in Haskell (part of the justification for purity and a very strong/expressive type system is actually to make this easier). But with monads (including IO) you do it by "lifting" functions *into* the monad to operate on values there, not by getting the values *out* of the monad to then feed to your functions.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained that the correct type of your function has to be `Filename -> IO OHLCBarList`, I'd like to try and give you some insight as to *why* the compiler imposes this draconian measure on you.

Imperative programming is all about managing state: "do certain operations to certain bits of memory in sequence". When they grow large, procedural programs become brittle; we need a way of limiting the scope of state changes. OO programs encapsulate state in classes but the paradigm is not fundamentally different: you can call the same method twice and get different results. The output of the method depends on the (hidden) state of the object.

Functional programming goes all the way and bans mutable state entirely. A Haskell function, when called with certain inputs, will always produce the same output. Simple examples of 
*pure functions* are mathematical operators like `+` and `*`, or most of the list-processing functions like `map`. Pure functions are all about the inputs and outputs, not managing internal state.

This allows the compiler to be very smart in optimising your program (for example, it can safely collapse duplicated code for you), and helps the programmer not to make mistakes: you can't put the system in an invalid state if there is none! We like pure functions.

The exception to the rule is IO. Code that performs IO is impure by definition: you could call `getLine` a hundred times and never get the same result, because it depends on what the user typed. Haskell handles this using the type system: **all impure functions are marred with the `IO` type**. `IO` can be thought of as a dependency on the state of the real world, sort of like `World -> (NewWorld, a)`

To summarise: pure functions are good because they are easy to reason about; this is why Haskell makes functions pure by default. Any impure code has to be labelled as such with an `IO` type signature; this tells the compiler and the reader to be careful with this function. So your function which reads from a file (a fundamentally impure action) but returns a pure value can't exist.

---

**Addendum in response to your comment**

You can still write pure functions to operate on data that was obtained impurely. Consider the following straw-man:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter the numbers you want me to process, separated by spaces"
    line <- getLine
    let numberStrings = words line
    let numbers = map read numberStrings
    putStrLn $ "The result of the calculation is " ++  (show $ foldr1 (*) numbers + 10)
```

Lots of code inside `IO` here. Let's extract some functions:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter the numbers you want me to process, separated by spaces"
    result <- fmap processLine getLine  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
                                        -- runs an impure result through a pure function
                                        -- without leaving IO
    putStrLn $ "The result of the calculation is " ++ result

processLine :: String -> String  -- look ma, no IO!
processLine = show . calculate . readNumbers

readNumbers :: String -> [Int]
readNumbers = map read . words

calculate :: [Int] -> Int
calculate numbers = product numbers + 10

product :: [Int] -> Int
product = foldr1 (*)
```

I've pulled logic out of `main` into **pure functions** which are easier to read, easier for the compiler to optimise, and more reusable (and so more testable). The program as a whole still lives inside `IO` because the data is obtained impurely (see the last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643143/1523776) for a more thorough treatment of this argument). Impure data can be piped through pure functions using `fmap` and other combinators; you should try to put as little logic in `main` as possible.

Your code does seem to be most of the way there; as others have suggested you could extract lines 2-4 of your `main` into another function.

Comment: Yes, I understand all this. See my comment further down on this topic.

Comment: There should be a 1 (accumulator) before 'numbers' in the very last line. More importantly, in the context of your example, what I would have liked here was a function that fetched that string (from somewhere, defined independently, could be from disk, interactive, listening to a socket, etc) and returned it as a list of numbers (or IO [Int], I suppose) ready to be processed.  Now perhaps as I improve my Haskell skills, I SHOULDN'T want that, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my typo ;) A key advantage of this style of programming - breaking everything up into small, pure functions - is that it's easy to combine them however you like. The function you describe - `getNumbers :: IO [Int]` - can be defined as `fmap readNumbers getLine`. If you need `calculateString :: String -> Int`, well, that's just `calculate . readNumbers`. It's like Lego - lots of small building blocks that you can take apart and put back together.

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, how can I implement (without getting all sorts of errors about IO stuff) the function whose type would be
>
> ```
> getBarsFromFile :: Filename -> OHLCBarList
> ```
>
> so that the grunt work that was being done in the first four lines of main can be properly encapsulated?

You cannot do this without getting all sorts of errors about IO stuff because this type for `getBarsFromFile` misses an `IO`. Probably that's what the errors about IO stuff are trying to tell you. Did you try understanding and fixing the errors?

In your situation, I would start by abstracting over the second to fourth line of your main in a function:

```
parseBars :: ByteString -> OHLCBarList
```

And then I would combine this function with `getContentsOfFile` to get:

```
getBarsFromFile :: FilePath -> IO OHLCBarList
```

This I would call in `main`.