# Type errors when using IO action in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I just started learning Haskell and now got stuck in dealing with IO action.

Here's the code.

```
parseDnsMessage :: BG.BitGet DnsMessage

recQuery :: BS.ByteString -> String -> IO BS.ByteString

resolveName :: [Word8] -> [Word8] -> BS.ByteString -> String
resolveName qname name bstr = do
  let newbstr = BSL.toStrict $ replace (BS.pack qname) (BS.pack name) bstr
  retbstr <- recQuery newbstr (head rootServers4)
  let msg = BG.runBitGet retbstr parseDnsMessage
  case msg of
    Right m -> (intercalate "." $ map show (rdata $ head $ answer $ m))
```

---Error Message---

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[BSI.ByteString]’
            with actual type ‘IO BSI.ByteString’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  retbstr <- recQuery newbstr (head rootServers4)
In the expression:
  do { let newbstr
             = BSL.toStrict $ replace (BS.pack qname) (BS.pack name) bstr;
       retbstr <- recQuery newbstr (head rootServers4);
       let msg = BG.runBitGet retbstr parseDnsMessage;
       case msg of {
         Right m
           -> (intercalate "." $ map show (rdata $ head $ answer $ m)) } }
```

I just want to retrieve `BS.ByteString` from the `recQuery` `IO action`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem is your `resolveName` should return `IO String`, not `String`. This is because it is operating in the `IO` monad, i.e. you are chaining `IO` actions in it, so it must return `IO`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [convert IO String to “Other type”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15641584/1523776)

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Thank you very much.

Comment: @WillSewell since your comment resolved the question, perhaps it should be posted as an answer?

Comment: @sclv ok I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your resolveName should return `IO String`, not `String`. This is because it is operating in the `IO` monad, i.e. you are chaining `IO` actions in it, so it must return `IO`.